# VBScript to click buttons

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to write a program in VBScript to automate tasks that I do in Internet Explorer. I need to click a series of buttons and textboxes and I was wondering if someone could give me a hint on how to get VBScript to click them for me?

At the moment I am just telling my program to click "tab" to get to the button I want and click "enter" - which makes the program really slow. I also need to enter data into a series of textboxes and click a button that will add another textbox for me to enter information in.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hake you looked at WatIn? http://watin.org/

Answer (score 0):

Right click the button you want in VBscript to click.
Click `Inspect Element`.

Find the Element ID of the button.

Make VBscript click the button like the example below:

```
Document.getElementById("IDGOESHERE").Click
```